# Entity Framework Tools for VS 2008 RTM (.net 3.5 sp1)

Tags: visual-studio-2008, entity-framework, entity

I'm trying to add ADO.NET Entity Data Model in my project but i can't access/find it. I found this [link text](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=09A36081-5ED1-4648-B995-6239D0B77CB5&displaylang=en) but it requires VS2008 Beta 3.5 version while mine is vs2008 RTM 3.5, is there a way i could install this?

Answer (score 0):

The tools ship with 2008 SP 1 RTM. There is no separate download.

Create a project, *then* add an EF model.

If that doesn't work, ask a more specific question.